# Django display uploading files in different fields

Tags: python, django

I am creating a system with Django. A user has several customers. And every customer has a different file upload field. I have upload functions but it is common for everyone. What I want is for every customer should have different pdf upload and display field. How can I do that?

**models.py**

```
class Pdf(models.Model):

    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select')
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def pdf_list(request):
    pdfs = Pdf.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pdf_list.html', {'pdfs': pdfs})


def upload_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('pdf_list')
    else:
        form = PdfForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_pdf.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class PdfForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = [
        ('img', 'Image'),
        ('txt', 'Text'),
    ]

    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    year = forms.fields.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    comp_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CompanyProfile.objects.all(), required=False,
                                       widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

**customer/model.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Choose")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your "different file upload field". a directory in your filesystem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield) to your Customer model (if several uploads per client are allowed you may need another model there) and populate it accordingly in your view